# How to access github repository

Tags: github, repository

I am brand new to github.  I made a repo a week ago and already forgot how to access it from the mac terminal.  So I just made a clone of a github repository online, how do I access that clone?  Where is located?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the terminal. 'cd' into the directory in which you wish to clone the project.

Once in the directory. You have to initialize git using

```
 git init
```

At this point, if you have any files in that folder you can add them using

```
git add .
```

The . means all files, if you wish to specify specific files then it is

```
git add index.html
```

once you have added. You commit using.

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Once committed, you add it to remote

```
git remote add origin {like to your repo}
```

Last step is to push it, using

```
git push -u origin master
```

Master referes to the master branch.

If you want a simple way out. use https://desktop.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you, follow the steps given below

- "cd" to desired directory
- clone the repo with the clone url
- git clone (here put https link)

  please review the link for the reference.

  https://gist.github.com/albatrocity/1201187

Answer (score 0):

When you write in the terminal:

```
git clone 'url of your repo'
```

It will make a copy of it inside the current directory. I don't know where you typed the command but it will be there. 
If you used one of those programs with visual interface you probably should look in the preferences, if it didn't ask you where you wanted to clone the repo it probably has some default.

Btw: even if it's harder at the beginning.. Learn how to use git from the command line